# Android Studio: ¿Cómo pasar datos desde un Adapter a un recyclerview del mismo fragmento?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

tengo un fragment que contiene un recyclerview que muestra categorías, lo que deseo es que al dar clic en alguna de las categorías se muestren en otro recyclerview(del mismo fragment) los productos correspondientes a la categoría.............productos que tengo almacenados en firebase.

A continuación adjunto los códigos del adapter y la clase HomeFragment donde deseo mostrar los productos:

Adapter de Categorias

```
public class CategInicioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategInicioAdapter.ViewHolder>{

Context context;
List<ModeloCategInicio> modeloCategInicioList;


public CategInicioAdapter(Context context, List<ModeloCategInicio> modeloCategInicioList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modeloCategInicioList = modeloCategInicioList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategInicioAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.categoria_item,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategInicioAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModeloCategInicio modeloCategoriasInicio = modeloCategInicioList.get(position);
    Glide.with(context).load(modeloCategoriasInicio.getImg_url()).into(holder.catImg);
    holder.nombre.setText(modeloCategoriasInicio.getNombre());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modeloCategInicioList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardCateg;
    ImageView catImg;
    TextView nombre;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardCateg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardcateg);
        catImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_cat_img);
        nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_home_name);
    }
}
}
```

Fragmento donde deseo que aparezcan los productos

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    //para mostrar nombre de usuario
    TextView nombreUser;

    //recyclerviews de inicio
    RecyclerView inicioCatRec,productosRec;

    //firebase
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    FirebaseDatabase database;

    //Categorias items
    List<ModeloCategInicio> modeloCategInicioList;
    CategInicioAdapter categInicioAdapter;

    //Productos items
    List<ModeloProducto> modeloProductoList;
    ProductosInicioAdapter productosInicioAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        inicioCatRec = root.findViewById(R.id.rec_categInicio);
        productosRec = root.findViewById(R.id.rec_prodInicio);
        nombreUser = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombreUser);

        //MOSTRAR NOMBRE DE USUARIO
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        ref.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String name = snapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
                nombreUser.setText(name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                System.out.println("Falló la operación: " + error.getCode());
            }
        });

        //CATEGORÍAS INICIO
        inicioCatRec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false));
        modeloCategInicioList = new ArrayList<>();
        categInicioAdapter = new CategInicioAdapter(getActivity(),modeloCategInicioList);
        inicioCatRec.setAdapter(categInicioAdapter);
        inicioCatRec.setHasFixedSize(true);
        inicioCatRec.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        db.collection("Categorias")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                ModeloCategInicio modeloCategInicio = document.toObject(ModeloCategInicio.class);
                                modeloCategInicioList.add(modeloCategInicio);
                                categInicioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        //PRODUCTOS INICIO
        productosRec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        modeloProductoList = new ArrayList<>();
        productosInicioAdapter = new ProductosInicioAdapter(getActivity(),modeloProductoList);
        productosRec.setAdapter(productosInicioAdapter);
        productosRec.setHasFixedSize(true);
        productosRec.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


        return root;
    }
}
```

Disculpen si no se me entiende, es la primera vez que publico aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Te explico como gestionar el click de un elemento de la lista por si no estás familiarizado con ello:

Crea una interfaz para el click, con una función cuyos argumentos serán los datos que necesites tener en el Fragment:

```
interface ProductListener {
    fun onProductClicked(position: Int, product: Product)
}
```

Desde el listener del objeto en el adapter llamas a la funcion de la interfaz:

```
itemView.clProduct.setOnClickListener { view: View? ->
    productListener!!.onProductClicked(
        mPosition,
        events[mPosition]
    )
}
```

Y desde el Fragment no tienes más que implementar la interfaz y hacer override de la función onProductClicked()

Luego ya puedes ocultar ese recyclerView y mostrar el del detalle del producto, o mostrar el nuevo recyclerView debajo del primero, o llamar a otro fragment para que lo muestre pasándole el producto.